# Problem converting HQL to Linq-to-NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate, nhibernate-3

How to convert this NHibernate HQL(works) ...

```
static IList<Phone> PhoneList()
{
    ISession session = OpenSession();

    IQuery query = session.CreateQuery("from Phone p where p.Kontact.ContactName = :_contact_name");
    query.SetParameter("_contact_name", "lennon");

    IList<Phone> contacts = query.List<Phone>();

    return contacts;        
}
```

...to Linq-to-NHibernate(not working):

```
static IList<Phone> PhoneListUsingLinq()
{
    string contactName = "lennon";

    ISession session = OpenSession();

    var contacts = from Phone p in session.Query<Phone>()
        where p.Kontact.ContactName == contactName
        select p;

    return contacts.ToList();

}
```

The objects:

```
public class Contact
{
    public virtual int ContactId { get; set; }
    public virtual string ContactName { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<Phone> Phones { get; set; }


}

public class Phone
{  
    public virtual Contact Kontact { get; set; }
    public virtual int PhoneId { set; get; }
    public virtual string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Here's the .hbm.xml mapping file of that two objects:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" auto-import="true" assembly="TestTwoTable" namespace="TestTwoTable">

  <class name="Contact" table="contact">
    <id name="ContactId" column="contact_id">
      <generator class="sequence">
        <param name="sequence">contact_contact_id_seq</param>
      </generator>
    </id>

    <property name="ContactName" column="contact_name"/>

    <bag name="Phones" inverse="true">
     <key column="contact_id"/>
     <one-to-many class="Phone"/>
    </bag>

  </class>

  <class name="Phone" table="phone">
    <id name="PhoneId" column="phone_id">
      <generator class="sequence">
        <param name="sequence">phone_phone_id_seq</param>
      </generator>
    </id>

    <property name="PhoneNumber" column="phone_number"/>

    <many-to-one name="Kontact" column="contact_id" class="Contact" not-null="true"/>

  </class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

What's wrong with this?

```
var contacts = from Phone p in session.Query<Phone>()
               where p.Kontact.ContactName == contactName
               select p;
```

Note: I'm using NHibernate 3

Comment: Change "from Phone p" to "from p"

Comment: Also, whats a "Kontact"?

Comment: Kontact is Contact. Btw, put your comment: **Change "from Phone p" to "from p"** to answer, so I can accept it as the answer. Didn't know it was that simple. Thanks very much!

Comment: Ah ok, because you can have the property name the same as the class name. public Contact Contact {get;set;}

Comment: Thanks, I knew that :-) When learning new stuff, I'm trying to disambiguate as much as possible. At first, I'm confused what's the **name** attribute refers to(is it the class' name? is it the instance of that class? same with property's **name**; if I'm using Sql Server, I might be led to believe that the class' properties names must conform strictly to actual database field names. I'm using Postgresql, CamelCase is not advisable), that's why I name things in an unambiguous way when learning. Next time, I would write it as Contact Contact, hbm.xml's name attributes are already clear to me :-)

Comment: Ah ok cool. It just made me confused. I don't know NHibernates hbm stuff, I used Fluent NHibernate. I hate XML :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change "from Phone p" to "from p"